# Scanner doesn't work in multiple methods?

Tags: java, methods, java.util.scanner

I used the Scanner class in the constructor and in another method and the error says that the Scanner is closed but I create two different scanner objects in each class. I realize that local variables will be deleted after the method finishes executing (even though execute is called before the constructor finished) But I thought making an object in each method should take care of that?

```
UserInterface() {
    System.out.println("Welcome! Which store would you like to look at?");
    Scanner scobj=new Scanner(System.in);
    storechoice=scobj.nextInt();
    printmenu();
    execute();
    //scobj.close();    
} 

public void execute() {
    Scanner scobj=new Scanner(System.in);
    String option1;
    int weekchoice;
    
    option1=scobj.nextLine();
    scobj.close();  
    
    switch(option1) {
        case "a":
            System.out.println("Which week?(0-4)");
            weekchoice=scobj.nextInt();
            f1.getStores(storechoice).totalsalesforweek(weekchoice);
            break;
            
        default:
            System.out.println("I'm sorry you must choose a-g or q to quit");
            break;
                
    }
}
```

I get these errors

> IllegalStateException:` Scanner closed
>
> ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
>
> next(Unknown Source)
>
> nextInt(Unknown Source)
>
> nextInt(Unknown Source)

Comment: Use same scanner for everything, no need to use several ones for same input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your "execute()" method, you close your scanner

```
scobj.close();
```

Then later, you do:

```
weekchoice=scobj.nextInt();
```

One the scanner is closed, calling "nextInt()" on it will crash your program.

Put "scobj.close();" at the **end** of your method, or wherever you are done using it.

It will end up looking like:

```
public void execute() 
    {
        Scanner scobj=new Scanner(System.in);
        String option1;
        int weekchoice;

        option1=scobj.nextLine();


        switch(option1)
        {
        case "a":
            System.out.println("Which week?(0-4)");
            weekchoice=scobj.nextInt();
            f1.getStores(storechoice).totalsalesforweek(weekchoice);
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("I'm sorry you must choose a-g or q to quit");
            break;

        }
        scobj.close(); 
    }
```

Comment: @MayaApotheker Make sure to upvote and accept answers that help you, and be sure to read the help articles for Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Once `Scanner` close, its internal input stream `System.in` is also closed.

Hence you can't access it anymore after you call `close()` method.

From javadoc:

> When a Scanner is closed, it will close its input source if the source implements the Closeable interface.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

I suggest you call `scObj.close()` at the end of your `main()` method only. Then you don't have to worry about this error in other methods anymore